# Style wont apply to angular component injected into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, iframe

I have an iframe in which i want to append my own angular component but it i cant get any styling to be applied to the component within the iframe.

On iframe load i add the component via js:

```
    let component= document.getElementById('componentId');
    let divInIframe= iframeWindow.document.getElementById('divInIframeId');
    divInIframe.appendChild(component);
```

The components own styling doesnt get applied so i tried to add it manually to the css to the iFrames own css file. Also tried to add style via js after iframe loads::

```
let cssLink = document.createElement("link");
    cssLink.href = "../../assets/component.css";
    cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
    cssLink.type = "text/css";
    iframDoc.head.appendChild(cssLink);
```

The styling still isnt applied to the component.

Tried ViewEncapsulation.None etc, but nothing seems to help.
Only way of making it work was to use encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom but that isnt supported in IE11.

Anyone got a clue how i can solve this?

Comment: How exactly are you planing to add it without bootstrapping the app?

Comment: I assume you have your purpose but why just one component with angular in that iframe and just not native Web component?

Comment: @Lucho I have a website build in angular that uses a library which serves a map into an iframe. I want to add my own buttons and stuff to that map. I cant just put them "on top" of the iframe with position absolute because of z-index related problems.

Comment: Gotcha, then do it the more "cleaner" way. Set a new angular app with only that component and load it in the iframe from its url as you do with your regular independent ng app. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Add the assets folder to the angular.json

```
"projects":{
   "AppName":{
      ...
      "assets":[
        "src/assets"
      ]
      ...
    }
 }
```

then use 
cssLink.href = "assets/component.css";

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell you is , when you append or inject any html into your component , any style or class will not be considerate by angular , this is the default behavior , what you can do is  change the encapsulation into encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.none ( highly unrecommended )  .
Or you can sanitize the external code by using the sanitizer .
I would recommende you to take a look at the [DomSanitizer documentation](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following:

```
selector: 'app-name',
templateUrl: './component_name.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./component_name.component.css']
```

Comment: Could you give a reason for doing this and why it would help